# Como mudar a codificação de multiplos arquivos de ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, codificação-de-caracteres, iso-8859-1

Eu tenho um projeto (em java) com mais de 100 arquivos, alguns deles estão em ISO outros em UTF8.

Como mudar a codificação de todos os arquivos de ISO para UTF-8 sem perder os caracteres especiais ?

Answer (score 3):

Se estiver usando o **Eclipse**:

1. Abra o Eclipse com seu projeto;
2. Na aba do "**Project Explorer**", clique com o botão direito e selecione **"Properties"**;
3. No menu esquerdo, escolha "**Resource**" e a direita, em "**Text File Encoding**" escolha UTF-8;
4. De OK em tudo;

Se estiver no **NetBeans**:

1. Abra o NetBean com seu projeto;
2. Na aba "**Projetos**" clique com o botão direito e selecione "**Propriedades**";
3. No menu a esquerda, selecione "**Códigos-Fonte**" e a direita, bem na parte inferior, altere a "**Codificação**" para UTF-8;

Como você disse que seu projeto tem mais de 100 arquivos em codificação diferente de UTF-8, e você irá altera-los, é bem provável que um monte de caracteres especiais quebrem (mesmo que você não queira). Por exemplo: "á" pode virar "�". E mais, se você ao compilar seu software, você poderá ter erro de ***[unmappable character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995057/unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8-error)***.

Faça um teste no NetBeans, eu fiz alguns testes aqui e não quebrou os caracteres especiais, diferentemente do Eclipse.

Comment: O UTF-8 inclui todos os caracteres do ISO-8859-1, portanto qualquer conversor bem feito deve conseguir converter os ficheiros todos sem caracteres de erro.

Comment: Fiz três testes aqui convertendo "áãâéêíîóú". Notepad++, Eclipse e Netbeans. Todos os testes convertendo de ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8. Resultado: quebra no Notepad++ e no Eclipse. No Netbeans, a conversão não quebrou caracteres especiais.

Comment: Se a conversão for bem feita, não quebra. Fiz a experiência em Notepad++ e funciona. (escolha explicitamente "Converter para UTF-8", não "Codificar em UTF-8")

Comment: Correto @luiscubal. Eu apenas trocava o encoding.

Answer (score 2):

É bom configurar seu editor para usar a codificação correta depois, mas inicialmente é muito melhor converter os arquivos de maneira automática.

Se estiver em algum Unix, basta usar o recode:

```
$ recode utf8 *.java
```

Para processar recursivamente:

```
$ find . -name "*.java" -exec recode utf8 {} \;
```

O recode é bastante flexível, dá para fazer muito mais coisas.
Créditos para esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/691065/340862).